# How can I make Zap synchronize with the Bitcoin network?

Tags: lightning-network, synchronization, zap

I'm using the Mac operating system. I downloaded [`Lightning App`](https://github.com/lightninglabs/lightning-app) and [`Zap`](https://github.com/LN-Zap/zap-desktop) from Github.

The wallet can not be synchronized with the network, how can I synchronize it and can I do it without having to download the full blockchain?

Lightning App shows me the error `the network can not be synchronized...`,
when I launch Lightning App it also pops up an error: `Syncing to chain ... block height: 0`.

When I launch Zap:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Connect Failed
    at ClientReadableStream._emitStatusIfDone (/Applications/Zap.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:255:19)
    at ClientReadableStream._readsDone (/Applications/Zap.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:221:8)
    at readCallback (/Applications/Zap.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:283:12)
```

What am I missing to get Lightning to run?

Answer (score 1):

To run the wallets you mentioned, you will need to also run a bitcoin node (`bitcoind` or `btcd`, most likely), and an `lnd`node as well. This information is listed in the README files on the pages you linked to.

I believe there are lightning network wallets that work without a local full node, but I don’t have experience with one so you’ll have to dig a bit to find one that works for you. NOTE: without running a node on your machine, you will be trusting someone else’s node in order to use the lightning network.